# Google Calendar API: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, google-api-java-client

```
We are trying to access the users calendar for Google workspace users(formally G Suite) using google calendar API via Google cloud platform (GCP)

We followed the following setup.

1) Set up domain-wide delegation for a client Ref link (https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en)

2) We have created a service account with an email id and got the client id as per the article above article.

3) We have then assigned Calendar API to created client id with read-only permission with below scopes
a> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly
b> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly
c> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.settings.readonly

4) Now at this point we are unable to see others users calendars except own and get the above error.

5) Also, when I tried accessing the Calendar events listing using the Google Api portal (https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list?apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22bizzhub%40embibe.com%22%7D), I was able to authorize and see the events.

I tried accessing the events I created on the calendar using the google apis. But, I keep getting the below error.
```

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404
> Not Found
>
> {
>
> "code" : 404,
>
> "errors" : [ {
>
> ```
> "domain" : "global",
>
> "message" : "Not Found",
>
> "reason" : "notFound"
> ```
>
> } ],
>
> "message" : "Not Found"
>
> }
>
> at
> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
>
> at
> com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
>
> at
> com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
>
> at
> com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
>
> at
> com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
>
> at
> com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
>
> at
> com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
>
> at
> com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
>
> at GoogleCalendarUtil2.getEventsList(GoogleCalendarUtil2.java:49)
>
> at GoogleCalendarMain.call(GoogleCalendarMain.java:13)
>
> at GoogleCalendarMain.main(GoogleCalendarMain.java:7)

Below is the code

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "smartworkspace2020",
  "private_key_id": "d6c2122d26ab25f908cf66d06a5ead1f77d7f013",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "bizzhub-2020-219@smartworkspace2020.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "117169030512379080380",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/bizzhub-2020-219%40smartworkspace2020.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. We cant help you debug an error message without seeing the code.

Comment: Is bizzhub@abc.com in the same domain as the service account and all the users you try to impersonate? Did you enable domain-wide delegation for the service account? And yes, please show your code and explain in detail how you set up your sercice account (GCP console, admin console).

Comment: Hi @DaImTo - i have added the code which I am passing using Jason file

Comment: What you provided is not a code but the content of the credentialsJavascripton file. What you did not show is how you implemented this credentials file to create a client instance andd perform the list request with this instance.